# Index is nil in each loop (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

So I am attempting to make a small function called titleize. It takes in a string, splits it by spaces into an array, and if it is a qualifying word (the first word or any words that is not one of the following: the, and over), capitalizes it before joining the array with spaces.

I had viewed several Ruby style guides and they warn against using the for/while loops in favor of the languages built in times and each loops. Since the domain of my problem requires the index and arrays are both iteratable and indexable in Ruby, I attempted to use an each loops with two arguments, item and index. My issue is that my index is nil (I have tested this). Is my syntax wrong or am I missing something? I looked around online and I could not find anything pertaining to this as well as similar questions. This is my first question and I would like to apologize upfront if I am missing anything from the rules while making this post.

What it should do:
"the bridge over the river kwai" -> "The Bridge over the River Kwai"
What it does:
"the bridge over the river kwai" -> "the Bridge over the River Kwai"

```
def titleize(string)
  words = string.split
  capitalized_words = []
  words.each do |word, index|
    #adds words if they are the first word or not one of the following: and, the, over
    if(!(word == "and" || word == "the" || word == "over") || index == 0)
      capitalized_words.push(word.capitalize)
    else
      capitalized_words.push(word)
    end
  end
  capitalized_words.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Sounds like homework, either from school or a tutorial. "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" brings up some considerations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` does not give you the index. Try with `each_with_index`

```
words.each_with_index do |word, index|
```

Anyway, I'd do this this way

```
TO_NOT_CAPITALIZE =  %w(and the over)

def titleize(string)
  string.split.each_with_index.map do |word, index| 
    index.zero? || !TO_NOT_CAPITALIZE.include?(word) ? word.capitalize : word 
  end.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you for letting me into the light of the different implementations of iterators :)

Comment: my pleasure sir